# HSQLDB 2.3.3: How do I return an array of next values for a sequence

Tags: hsqldb

I have a stored procedure to return the next value for a sequence, but I need the next "N" values for a sequence. I'd like to pass in N as the NUMBEROFIDS parameter, see below. Then the OUT GENERATEDID would be an ARRAY instead. Is this even possible in HSQLDB?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MY_PROCEDURE(
    IN NUMBEROFIDS NUMERIC,
    OUT GENERATEDID NUMERIC)

    MODIFIES SQL DATA   

    BEGIN ATOMIC

    SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR MY_SEQUENCE INTO GENERATEDID FROM MY_TABLE;

    END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the parameter as an ARRAY and use a loop to populate an array.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MY_PROCEDURE(
 IN NUMBEROFIDS INTEGER,
 OUT GENERATEDID NUMERIC ARRAY)
 BEGIN ATOMIC
  DECLARE GENID NUMERIC ARRAY;
  DECLARE COUNTER INTEGER DEFAULT 1;
  WHILE COUNTER <= NUMBEROFIDS DO
   SET GENID[COUNTER] = NEXT VALUE FOR MY_SEQUENCE;
  END WHILE;
  SET GENERATEDID = GENID;
 END;
```